# Why doesn't it work to write a Windows ISO to an USB drive using dd?

Tags: linux, windows-10, debian, dvd, iso-image

For Debian Linux you can simply copy the installation ISO to an USB drive without modifying one single bit using `dd`. It's also possible to burn the ISO to a DVD without any modification.

But Windows installation ISOs can only be burned to DVDs. It's not possible to write them to an USB drive directly using `dd`. You need additional tools like Rufus or Unetbootin.

Why is that?

(I am talking about Windows 10 ISOs but I think it applies to other Windows versions too.)

Comment: I believe its because the image format is ISO-9660, a format for spinning optical media. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660

Comment: @FrankThomas This does not answer why Debian ISOs work. However I found the answer in the duplicate question.